# Nouislider slider is not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nouislider

I using the below code to intialise the nouilslider-react. But it's css is not being loaded. What should I do?
I have imported the react-nouislider. Functionalities are working fine. But I am seeing the sliders as text like below

[image]

```
<SliderInput
   range={{min: 0, max: 200}}
   start={[0, 100]}
   tooltips
   />
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

u have to add some style on that slider

try this example style.css code below (from https://codepen.io/mshwery/pen/CBslE)

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.no-ui-slider {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

/* Functional styling;
 * These styles are required for noUiSlider to function.
 * You don't need to change these rules to apply your design.
 */
.noUi-target,
.noUi-target * {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-touch-action: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.noUi-base {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.noUi-origin {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.noUi-handle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.noUi-stacking .noUi-handle {
/* This class is applied to the lower origin when
   its values is > 50%. */
    z-index: 10;
}
.noUi-stacking + .noUi-origin {
/* Fix stacking order in IE7, which incorrectly
   creates a new context for the origins. */
    *z-index: -1;
}
.noUi-state-tap .noUi-origin {
-webkit-transition: left 0.3s, top 0.3s;
    transition: left 0.3s, top 0.3s;
}
.noUi-state-drag * {
    cursor: inherit !important;
}

/* Slider size and handle placement;
 */
.noUi-horizontal {
    height: 10px;
}
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: -10px;
    top: -7px;
}
.noUi-horizontal.noUi-extended {
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.noUi-horizontal.noUi-extended .noUi-origin  {
    right: -15px;
}

/* Styling;
 */
.noUi-background {
    background: #3182bd;
}
.noUi-connect {
    background: #3FB8AF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.45);
-webkit-transition: background 450ms;
    transition: background 450ms;
}
.noUi-origin {
    border-radius: 2px;
  background: #eee;
}
.noUi-target {
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.noUi-target.noUi-connect {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.45), 0 3px 6px -5px #BBB;
}

/* Handles and cursors;
 */
.noUi-dragable {
    cursor: w-resize;
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-dragable {
    cursor: n-resize;
}
.noUi-handle {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: default;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
.noUi-active {

}

/* Handle stripes;
 */
.noUi-handle:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
  border-top: 11px solid #fff;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.noUi-handle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -0px;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-top: 11px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

/* Disabled state;
 */
[disabled].noUi-connect,
[disabled] .noUi-connect {
    background: #B8B8B8;
}
[disabled] .noUi-handle {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```